# Ninject WithConstructorArgument to Simple Injector Implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, simple-injector

What is the direct implementation from Ninject's `WithConstructorArgument` to a Simple Injector implementation?

```
 var emailTemplates = new EmailTemplates
 {
      MasterPageTemplate = MVC.Email.Views._Layout
 };

 container.Register<IEmailService, EmailService>()
     .WithConstructorArgument("templates", emailTemplates);
```

**Class**

```
public EmailTemplatesService(
            EmailTemplates templates,
            IEventEmailTemplatesRepository eventEmailTemplatesRepository)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Simple Injector, you can do this:

```
container.Register<IEmailService>(() => new EmailService(
    emailTemplates,
    container.GetInstance<IEventEmailTemplatesRepository>()));
```

Or you can do this:

```
// Wrap the string value into a DTO and inject that
public EmailService(
    EmailServiceSettings settings, IEventEmailTemplatesRepository r) { ... }

container.RegisterInstance(new EmailServiceSettings(emailTemplates));
container.Register<IEmailService, EmailService>();
```

Or you can override the parameter injection behavior, as explained [here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=94).

Comment: I added the contructor, what about the second argument.  This is for another translation, but I think it would work well for the same question here.

Comment: I see pretty nice setup, what if you had 10 contructor repositories to inject.  Do a `container.GetInstance` for everyone?